# Next Build hangs forever

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, yarnpkg, npm-scripts

I'm building an app with NextJs and Typescript. I'm trying to run next build (`yarn build`) on my local machine to check for typescript warnings and build errors before deploying.

Next build hangs at 'Creating an optimized production build' and hangs forever. Don't even know where to start to address this issue. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 28):

Could be a [cache issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9410).

I'd start by removing `/.next` folder, if it didn't work then both `/.next` and `/node_modules`. Whenever you have issues with Next you don't know how to approach or it's just acting weird - removing `/.next` will solve most of the problems.

Comment: Also, make sure that your server isn't running in the background. Happened to me.

Comment: That's work after finding a solution for 5 days. Thaks a lot brother.

Answer (score 4):

Have found the solution to the issue. Apparently the build freeze was caused by empty files located all over my project directory. Removed all of them and next build runs

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue too.

I solved it by upgrading node version from `v16.13.0` to `v16.14.0`.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you stoped all servers that running in the background
Use `npx kill-port 3000`

Answer (score 2):

Tried all the excellent suggestions here, but for me the problem was with optimizing one of the external packages. Since performance wasn't a big issue for me, skipping minifying solved it.

You need this in your next.config.js:

```
const nextConfig = {
  swcMinify: false, // 'minify' in Next versions < 12.0
}
```

And to make sure this works, I reiterated all the above comments to make sure I wasn't hanging on one of the billion previous attempts :)

Answer (score 1):

**You can't have both dev and build at the same time.**

> I solved it very quickly when I realized that there were several
> nodejs processes open when there should only be 1, and killing all the
> nodejs processes that were running in the background solved it for me.

It can also happen that a build started to fail and got stuck in the background so you should kill all the nodejs you see running in the task manager. I am using Nextjs 13

Comment: this worked for me. I tried building 3 times and I get confused why its taking so much time. lol

Answer (score 0):

So the issue with it was that I had an empty file somewhere in the app. Apparently the empty file was what was hanging the build

Answer (score 0):

check the development server (npm run dev). If it's running stop it.
delete this folders & file : next, node_modules, package-lock.json

```
rm -rf .next/ node_modules/ package-lock.json
```

I fixed the problem with these

Answer (score -1):

I solved it ***downgrading*** npm version ***to v8.5.5***. I was testing using v8.12.2 and it always keep in "Checking validity of types"