# Stuck on Creating an optimized production build

Tags: next.js, vercel

I'm trying to deploy my app to Vercel, but it has been in the same message forever.

My Code: https://github.com/Yash-Popcorn/Yash-Popcorn-Portfolio

Deployment Status

`

```
Cloning github.com/Yash-Popcorn/Yash-Popcorn-Portfolio (Branch: main, Commit: ed0285b)
The cli flag --force was set. Skipping build cache download.
Cloning completed: 343.643ms
Running "vercel build"
Vercel CLI 28.4.17
Installing dependencies...
added 340 packages in 10s
78 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
Detected Next.js version: 13.0.2
Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+...
Running "npm run build"
> portfolio@0.1.0 build
> next build
Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
https://nextjs.org/telemetry
info  - Linting and checking validity of types...
info  - Creating an optimized production build...
```

`

I tried to run with build cache and without build cache.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue when running `npm run build` locally?

Comment: Several things to try here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67956337/next-build-hangs-forever (possible duplicate)